# Generalized expression for balls and bins problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$n$ number of balls are thrown randomly to $m$ number of bins, standing in a row. The balls are labeled as $1,2,3,....n$ and bins are also labeled as $1,2,3,...,m$. The probability of $i_{th}$ ball enters in the $j_{th}$ bin is $p_{ij}$. What is the expected number of balls enter in the same bin when all $n$ balls are thrown simultaneously?

I solved the problem for $n=2;m=2$ in the following way

$E(x=$number of balls enter in the same bin$)=((p_{11}.p_{12})+(p_{12}.p_{21})).1 + ((p_{11}.p_{21})+(p_{12}.p_{22})).2$

I don't know how to express the above procedure for $n$ balls and $m$ bins in a generalized way using mathematical notations. I am also interested to know if there is any simplified formula to calculate this because that may reduce the computational complexity.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "average number of balls in the same bin"? For example, for $n=m=2$ you have one case where there are $2$ balls in one of the bins but $0$ balls in the other. So I would have said the average number of balls in a single bin is $1$ in that case, but you seem to be saying it is $2$. Are you looking actually for the expected _maximum_ number of balls that will fall in any single bin?

Comment: @David K,Thanks for your reply. I am looking for the expected number of balls in the same bin.(just corrected).

Comment: The mean number of balls per bin is $\frac{n}{m}$. (One can think of this as obvious, or give a more formal proof.) But this is too simple, perhaps you are asking for something more complicated, like the mean number of balls per *occupied* bin.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas,That's correct. In this case average number of balls per "occupied" bin depends on the probability $p_{ij}$ and its complex because $p_{ij}$ is different for different $i$ and $j$. If $m=3,n=3$ then $E(x)=P(x=1).1+p(x=2).2+p(x=3).3$ where P(x=k) is the probability of k number of balls in the same bin.